# First letters of a Tkinter input

Tags: python, input, tkinter

My program should check if the first three letters of the input word are similar to a predefined word.
I've made a GUI with Tkinter and want to get the letters of the input field.
Somehow I can't implement it in like I would do without Tkinter.

That's how I do it just for the shell:

```
text = raw_input('Enter a word: ')

if (text[0] + text[1] + text[2] == 'sag'):
    print "sagen"
else:
    print "error"
```

So, when I input the word "sagst" it checks the first three letters and should put out "sagen". Works fine.

I learned that e.g. `inputfield.get()` gets the input of the entry "inputfield".
**But how can I check the first letters of that "inputfield"?**
A small selection:

```
from Tkinter import*
root = Tk()

def check():
    if (text[0] + text[1] + text[2] == 'sag'):
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"

inputfield = Entry(root)
inputfield.pack()

but = Button(root,text='Check!', command = check)
but.pack()

text = inputfield.get()

root.mainloop()
```

Does not work...

I hope you can understand my question and will answer soon. (Sorry for my bad english and my bad Python skills) ;-)
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: slicing works great on strings: `text[:3] == 'sag'`. Even better, python strings have a `.startswith()` function: `text.startswith('sag')`.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "does not work", what does it do wrong? *Also, you can slice your text: `text[0:3]` which is the same as `text[0] + text[1] + text[2]`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `check` function will have to retrieve the textfield *after* the button has been pressed:

```
def check():
    text = inputfield.get()
    print text.startswith('sag')
```

I've changed your test a little, using [`.startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith), and directly printing the result of that test (print will turn boolean `True` or `False` into the matching string).

What happens in your code is that you define `inputfield`, retrieve it's contents (obviously empty), and only *then* show the TKInter GUI window by running the mainloop. The user never gets a chance to enter any text that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check this without the need for a button (Now it will check whenever the user presses "Enter"):

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def check(*event):
    text = inputfield.get()
    print text.startswith('sag')

inputfield = Entry(root)
inputfield.bind('<Return>',check)
inputfield.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

You can also do other things to have your widget [validate the entry as you type](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-entry-validate.htm).  (The link is old, but it also points to newer features that allow you to do this without subclassing).

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually putting the value in the input field into the text variable.

I renamed the value from text to input_text because it was confusing to me.  I also changed from using `text[0] + text[1] + text[2]` to using `startswith()`.  This will keep you from getting IndexErrors on short strings, and is much more pythonic.

```
from Tkinter import*
root = Tk()

def check():
    input_text = inputfield.get()
    if input_text.startswith('sag'):
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"

inputfield = Entry(root)
inputfield.pack()



input_text = inputfield.get()
print input_text # Note that this never prints a string, because it only prints once when the input is empty.

but = Button(root, text='Check!', command=check)
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The key change is that the `check` function needs to actually get the value in the `inputfield`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `text` as a variable name actually. It doesn't shadow any built-in functions or types, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which uses an Entry widget which validates its contents as the user types (so the user does not have to click a button or even press Return).

```
import Tkinter as tk
class MyApp(object):
    '''
    http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-entry-validate.htm
    http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm
    http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M-validate
    '''
    def __init__(self, master):
        vcmd = (master.register(self.validate),
                '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(master, validate = 'key',
                              validatecommand = vcmd)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.focus()

    def validate(self, action, index, value_if_allowed,
                   prior_value, text, validation_type, trigger_type, widget_name):
        dtype = {'0':'delete', '1':'insert', '-1':'other'}[action]
        n = min(3, len(value_if_allowed))
        valid = False
        if dtype == 'insert':
            if value_if_allowed[:n] == 'sag'[:n]: valid = True
            else: valid = False
        else: valid = True
        print(valid)
        return True

root = tk.Tk()
app = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```